# Non stop stream to rtmp with FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp3, rtmp

I want to stream to RTMP with FFMPEG. I need to dynamically change next play file, for that i use web urls for my localhost.

I have PHP file located: http://127.0.0.1/mp3.php

```
$file = '1.mp3';

$mime_type = "audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3";

if(file_exists($file)){
    header('Content-type: {$mime_type}');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $file);
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    readfile($file);
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

And i run ffmpeg with this command line:

`ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i logo.png -stream_loop -1 -i http://127.0.0.1/mp3.php -ab 320k -c:v libx264 -f flv "rtmp://ms......."`

This works, but it playing only once time and FFMPEG returns an error:

`Seek to start failed
http://127.0.0.1/mp3.php: Function not implemented`

How can i fix it?

Comment: Seek to start failed - function not implemented is a pretty specific error message telling you exactly why it cannot do what you ask. ffmpeg cannot "rewind" and continue playing. Maybe there is another way to achieve what you want, e.g. run the play command again?

Comment: Idk why FFMPEG cant play files from url as loop, but this working correctly if i replace url to direct path to file :(

Comment: so it can seek a local file, but it cannot seek an online stream. That seems reasonable. you're running into technical limits of media streaming, that's not a problem in the ffmpeg software.